# IOTA MAM messaging with node.js server

Tags: node.js, iota

-I'm using (https://github.com/xdk2mam/xdk2mam/tree/Workbench-3.6/http-sdcard).
-I'm not versed on JS so I'm not understanding the problem here.
-I'm trying to send a string of sensor data to the tangle and listen to it using a node.js server.
-I keep getting either ECONNREFUSED or ECONNRESET and Protocol not supported(but I think I get when this last one happens, but I don't really understand why.
-I'm trying to use comnet [I assumed it would be for such tasks]
-(https://comnet.tanglebay.com/) 
-(https://api.lb-0.testnet.chrysalis2.com/) 
-with port 15600
-I'm also trying to get my node up and running to test such things but still don't have enough peers to sync to(but the node is running).

-Correct me if I'm wrong but my understanding is: 
-IOTA messaging(gossip) is free right? 
-So why would any Node deny the connection?
-So the problem must be in the connection, but if that's the case the reason escapes me.
-Do I need some kind of authorization from the node for the message to go trough? 
-Can anyone have a quick look and point me in the right direction?  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Powershell log]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by opening the respective port on the firewall. Got me another error now.
**connect ETIMEDOUT**

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using:
https://github.com/iot2tangle/XDK110-Bosch/tree/master/http-sdcard this is apparently working